# Insert "does it ever happen to you" question title in disguise here?

Tags: discussion

Insert self-aggrandizing question here.

---

Insert about 10 "Congratulations, looks like you are just as cool as me" answer here. Then insert a link to one of the top 10 frequently referenced books here.

---

Do exchanges like these add any value to this site?

A specific example of the question:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/48240/developing-instincts-and-subconscious-debugging

Comment: Hey Job, how I deal with being a perfectionist?  ;)

Answer (score 6):

Questions like that are already discouraged in the FAQ:

> **What kind of questions should I not
>   ask here?**
>
> You should only ask practical,
>   answerable questions based on actual
>   problems that you face. Chatty,
>   open-ended questions diminish the
>   usefulness of our site and push other
>   questions off the front page. To
>   prevent your question from being
>   flagged and possibly removed, avoid
>   asking subjective questions where …
>
> [...]
>   there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”

When you see questions like that, please flag them as "not constructive" or vote to close for the same reason if you have the rep to do so.

Comment: The FAQ is very thorough and well written. However, I think that anyone with the audacity to hit the 'Post Your Question' button after writing nonsensical, time-wasting gibberish has not read the FAQ. They probably can't read. Same for those that encourage the poster of nonsense (by answering, voting, and not flagging the post). But your point is shows good direction for the rest of the participants on this site.

Comment: @Jonathan Part of our job as moderators is to be familiar with the FAQ and enforce the guidelines. We leave comments on posts that we think go against them to remind and/or educate others that they exist. There will always be people who don't read the FAQ, so there will always be moderators. :)